# ELKI DBSCAN for million files

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, r-tree, dbscan, elki

I am using dbscan for clustering points, as my points are more than 1 million I use r*-tree too.

I use ELKI in command line:

```
java -cp elki.jar
de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.application.KDDCLIApplication
-db.index tree.spatial.rstarvariants.rstar.RStarTreeFactory
-algorithm clustering.DBSCAN
-dbc.in points1.txt
-dbscan.epsilon 20
-dbscan.minpts 10
-out results3/DBSCANeps20min10
```

for small files its ok but for 4 million files the error occurred:

```
at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.database.ids.integer.DoubleIntegerArrayQuickSort.quickSort(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Any chance you are using an old version of ELKI?
Also, use bulk loading for the R*-tree. Its *much* faster.

Comment: thanks @ErichSchubert, I used 0.6.0 version (2014, January, 10), the problem is for this?

Comment: Then it is this old problem. Please use the fixed, newer versions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in an **old version** of ELKI, when there are many duplicate distances.

It can be resolved by updating to a current version.